# How do I use a button to increase the value of a slider in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity and I don't know how to click a button and increase the value of a slider.

I have created a slider and its value decreases over time. Now I want to increase that value every time I click a button.

```
public class BarraAlimento : MonoBehaviour
{
  public const float alimentoMax = 100f;
  public float alimento;
  public Slider barraAlimento;

  void Start()
  {
    alimento = alimentoMax;
  }

  void Update()
  {
    barraAlimento.value = alimento;

    if (alimento <= 0)
    {
      alimento = 0;
    }
    else if (alimento > 0)
    {
      alimento -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
  } 
}
```

That's the script of the slider, but I don't know how to do the button one.

Comment: You could further improve your code by changing the `else if (...)` into an `else`, since the second condition is not necessary.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with unity. Is there a click event for a button like in winforms.
If so, try putting your code into there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to declare a button and get the onClick event. After that, increase the value as you see fit.

```
  public Button _yourButton;


    void Start()
    {
        alimento = alimentoMax;
      _yourButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClicked);

    }

    void ButtonClicked()
    {
        //increase your value as you wish
        alimento += 1;
    }
```

Comment: In the lambda function, you're calling ButtonClicked without parameters, which won't work. You don't need to use a lambda function at all, you can just pass the function (the delegate) as a parameter. `_yourButton.onClick.AddListener(ButtonClicked);` and the ButtonClicked() function wouldn't take a parameter `void ButtonClicked() { ... }`.

Comment: @pravymravec You are right, forgot to remove that part. Edited the answer for simplicity and clearness. Thanks for the heads up!